# edit or append text (TextInput class) in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

`TextInput` class

Is there any way to append or edit text ???

Problem:

I created `TextInput` object and accessed text method to print strings.

But every time I access text method, it prints new string and it doesn't retain previous value.

How to fix the issue?

what is alternative for `TextInput`?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the text with some function of the original string, e.g. `textinput.text = ''.join('something ', textinput.text.replace('a', 'b'), ' and something else')`.